# Metodo POST não funcionando na mesma pagina

Tags: php, post

Ao tentar fazer upload de um arquivo ele da erro

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="file" name="inputfileSendTorrent">
<input type="submit" name="submitSendTorrent">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitSendTorrent']))
{   
    $uploaddir = '/arquivos/';
$arqName = $_FILES['inputfileSendTorrent']['name'];
$arqSize = $_FILES['inputfileSendTorrent']['size'];
$arqTemp = $_FILES['inputfileSendTorrent']['tmp_name'];
$upload = move_uploaded_file($arqTemp, $uploaddir . $arqName);
}
?>
```

Retorna o erro

```
Notice: Undefined index: inputfileSendTorrent in C:\xampp\htdocs\LuckTor2\pages\teste.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: inputfileSendTorrent in C:\xampp\htdocs\LuckTor2\pages\teste.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: inputfileSendTorrent in C:\xampp\htdocs\LuckTor2\pages\teste.php on line 11
```

Comment: No seu `php.ini` está setado `file_uploads = On`? Aproveite e verifique se o seu arquivo está dentro dos limites estabelecidos por outras variáveis no `php.ini`:`max_execution_time`,  `max_input_time`, `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: @leonardopessoa Esta sim.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` na tag form, é necessário quando há upload de arquivo.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

Comment: O erro desapareceu, porem ele ainda não esta enviando os arquivos para a pasta `/arquivos/`.

Comment: tente arquivos/ , sem a primeira barra

Comment: Acabei de tentar, porem ainda não funcionou, minha config esta `file_uploads=On` e `upload_max_filesize=2M`.

Comment: Descobri o problema, arquivos .RAR e pastas não funcionam, sabe o por que ??